# Add dash underline substring of UILabel text ios

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I have tried using below code snippet to achieve it,

```
testLabel.attributedText = getKnowMoreAttributedText()

func getAttributedString() -> NSAttributedString {
    let defaultAttr: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.darkText, .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0)]

    let resultStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Some random text. Dashed underline text", attributes: defaultAttr)

    let dashed =  NSUnderlineStyle.patternDot.rawValue | NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue

    resultStr.addAttributes([.underlineStyle : dashed], range: (resultStr.string as NSString).range(of: "Dashed underline text"))

    return resultStr
}
```

> Output: refer to screenshot below.

[image]

The problem is there is no space between dash undeline & text.

> Expected Output:

[image]

I have also tried using `UITextView` instead of `UILabel`, but no luck with that.

Comment: I think it is depend on what font you are using.

Comment: Currently I am using systemFont.

Comment: Try as below in link https://github.com/NimbusKit/attributedlabel